# Copy every nth column of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, sampling

How would you copy the first element and every element of the nth column in another array?

For example, supposed you have the array below:

```
array{[1,2,3,4,5],
      [1,2,3,4,5],
      [1,2,3,4,5]}
```

I want to choose the first element and every 2nd element so I would have:

```
array{[1,3,5],
      [1,3,5],
      [1,3,5]}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use slicing against the columns

```
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])

>>> a[:, ::2]
array([[1, 3, 5],
       [1, 3, 5],
       [1, 3, 5]])
```

As mentioned by [@tobias_k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1639625/tobias-k) if you want to make an actual copy of this sliced array, you can use [`numpy.copy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html) to make sure modifications don't affect the original array

```
>>> np.copy(a[:, ::2])
array([[1, 3, 5],
       [1, 3, 5],
       [1, 3, 5]])
```

Comment: Technically, this is not a copy, though, but just a view. Changing the resulting array will also change the original.

Comment: Thanks! This worked! I've missed the slicing against the columns. What I'm doing before is `numpy.copy(a[0::2])` which is different.